# SimpleDB dialect for NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, amazon-simpledb

Do you know if there is a way of using Amazon SimpleDB with NHibernate? [LightSpeed seems to be compatible](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/blog/index.php/2009/01/13/object-relational-mapping-over-amazon-simpledb-using-lightspeed/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate is more oriented to traditional SQL databases, so no. But you might want to check out [Linq To SimpleDB](http://www.codeplex.com/LinqToSimpleDB) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [Simple Savant](http://simplesavant.codeplex.com/), an open-source .NET persistence library designed specifically for SimpleDB (I'm the creator). SimpleDB is so different from a relational database that it would be difficult to use with NHibernate. But Simple Savant will get you many similar features.